# Require sorting on IP address using js

Tags: javascript

I am using https://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable for sorting the columns in my table. This works great without using any plugin or so.

But one column is of IP addresses and this script is not sorting the column for IP address. 
eg. If only I could sort below for IP address.

```
10.132.14.12
10.132.14.11
10.132.14.14
10.132.14.9
```

Please note that the IP addresses generated over here are automatic. So I cannot know what range of IP address I will receive.

Comment: What have you tried ? Did you try with a custom sort function ?

Comment: Have you gone thourh the API of the library. You need to define "custom sort keys"

Comment: include your code we can't help you if you didnt even include it

Comment: yes but that uses sorttable_customkey attribute and on the basis of that it sorts. In my case, I don't know what IP address would come. These IP addresses are generated in the report automatically.

Comment: @beginner, https://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js and I just used <table class=sortable> in my table.

Comment: @Weedoze, I did but this is not applicable in my case.

Comment: @9tocloud Why is it not applicable ? Show us some effort, show us what you tried and why it does not work

Answer (score 27):

Just adding my solution here if anyone ends up here after search:

```
arrayOfIps
.sort((a, b) => {
        const num1 = Number(a.split(".").map((num) => (`000${num}`).slice(-3) ).join(""));
        const num2 = Number(b.split(".").map((num) => (`000${num}`).slice(-3) ).join(""));
        return num1-num2;
});
```

You could also use padStart instead of slice, if you are using newer versions of nodejs.

Comment: I was just looking for this. And conveniently you've answered it just 2 days ago. Thanks!

Comment: Nice use of slice!

Answer (score 2):

This function makes numeric sort of IPv4 addresses:

```js
function compareIPAddresses(a, b) {
  const numA = Number(
    a.split('.')
      .map((num, idx) => num * Math.pow(2, (3 - idx) * 8))
      .reduce((a, v) => ((a += v), a), 0)
  );
  const numB = Number(
    b.split('.')
      .map((num, idx) => num * Math.pow(2, (3 - idx) * 8))
      .reduce((a, v) => ((a += v), a), 0)
  );
  return numA - numB;
}

const ipAddresses = [
  '10.132.14.12',
  '10.132.14.11',
  '10.132.14.14',
  '10.132.14.9',
];

const sorted = ipAddresses.sort(compareIPAddresses);

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine, I've just made a runnable snippet of it.

Answer (score 0):

To sort a list of IP address values you can convert them to their numeric expression. Next step is to sort the list of numeric values in ascending order.

For a large amount of IPs this is faster than parsing and converting string and templates as proposed before.

Have a look at: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ip

Answer (score 0):

DRY version of [Vasanth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48618635/require-sorting-on-ip-address-using-js#answer-51536936).

```
const makeIpNumber = (ip) => Number(
  ip.split('.')
    .map((subString) => (`00${subString}`).slice(-3))
    .join('')
);

arrayOfIps.sort((a, b) => makeIpNumber(a) - makeIpNumber(b));
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code allows you any type of string by matching its ip address using RegExp.

```js
const arrayLines = '100.98.242.115:DarkDAYSS16\n100.98.235.61:EnesAbii47\n100.98.236.188:Enesesme\n100.98.234.61:ParikmaxerKaya\n100.98.239.26:kino_moflos\nc\n1.1.1.1\n100.98.238.233:MaxFedoseev2007\n100.98.233.98:L20061212D\ndef\n100.98.236.145:enes125ht\n100.98.236.91:LOGAN_LOBEZNO888\n100.98.237.249:pequee192\nabc\n100.98.233.126:psh910\n100.98.238.56:LOSE-TODOO\n100.98.234.160:Marco_08capu\n100.98.239.182:Umut_Alinca\n100.98.241.52:kort196\n100.98.237.119:JoshAcco\n100.98.237.211:kevinowenss123\n100.98.240.64:Eren057_016\n100.98.240.117:aaronssalguero'.split('\n');
const regExp = /.*?(?<ip_address>(\b25[0-5]|\b2[0-4]\d|\b[01]?\d{1,2})(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d{1,2})){3})/;

const ip2long = (ip_address) => {
    let longValue = 0;
    for (const [index, part] of ip_address.split('.').entries()) longValue += part * [0x1_00_00_00, 0x1_00_00, 0x1_00, 1][index];
    return longValue;
}

// Response: (20) ['1.1.1.1', '100.98.233.98:L20061212D', '100.98.233.126:psh910', '100.98.234.61:ParikmaxerKaya', '100.98.234.160:Marco_08capu', '100.98.235.61:EnesAbii47', '100.98.236.91:LOGAN_LOBEZNO888', '100.98.236.145:enes125ht', '100.98.236.188:Enesesme', '100.98.237.119:JoshAcco', '100.98.237.211:kevinowenss123', '100.98.237.249:pequee192', '100.98.238.56:LOSE-TODOO', '100.98.238.233:MaxFedoseev2007', '100.98.239.26:kino_moflos', '100.98.239.182:Umut_Alinca', '100.98.240.64:Eren057_016', '100.98.240.117:aaronssalguero', '100.98.241.52:kort196', '100.98.242.115:DarkDAYSS16']
arrayLines.filter(string_ => string_.match(regExp) !== null).sort((a, b) => {
    let aMatchIPAddress = a.match(regExp),
        bMatchIPAddress = b.match(regExp);

    let aIP2long = ip2long(aMatchIPAddress.groups.ip_address),
        bIP2long = ip2long(bMatchIPAddress.groups.ip_address);

    return aIP2long - bIP2long;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let sortedIpArr = ipArr.sort((a, b) =>{

  return a.split('.')[0] - b.split('.')[0] || a.split('.')[1] - b.split('.')[1] || a.split('.')[2] - b.split('.')[2] || a.split('.')[3] - b.split('.')[3]
});

console.log("sorted ip arr: ", sortedIpArr);
```